# remove quotes wordpress form input

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a registration form in my wordpress site. The following is the code that i have used for register users.

```
$username = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['txtFullName']));
$email = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['txtEmail']));
$password = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['txtPassword']));
$confirmpassword = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['txtConfirmPassword']));
gender = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['gender']));

 $user_id = wp_insert_user( array ('user_pass' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_pass', $password), 'user_login' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_login', $username), 'user_email' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_email', $email), 'role' => 'author' ) );

$authid = $user_id;


 do_action('user_register', $user_id);

// Insert into Post table               
$post = array();
$post['post_author'] = $authid ;
$post['post_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ;
$post['post_date_gmt'] =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ;
$post['post_name'] = $username ;
$post['post_status'] = 'pending' ;
$post['post_title'] = $username ;
$post['post_type'] =  'post';
$post['post_category'] =  $gender;


wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
```

I am trying to insert the user in the posts table too after registered. If i entered the username like `test'name` it will be inserted as `testname` in user table but it will be inserted as `test\'name` in posts table. I have to remove the quotes in posts table too. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove quotes or any character with str_replace()

matching to your example:

```
$post['post_name'] = str_replace("'", "", $username);
```

Comment: i'm glad i could help you. but maybe you should search for some regex examples to remove some other 'delicate' characters too in one line of code.